# The method getInstance(Context) in the type GoogleCloudMessaging is not applicable for the arguments (XWalkResponceClient)

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-context, crosswalk

I want to register my application to GCM on xwalkview load but there I am not able to access context and getInstance() of GCM inside XWalkResponceClient.

```
@Override
public void onLoadStarted(XWalkView view, String url) {
  super.onLoadStarted(view, url);
  if (TextUtils.isEmpty(regId)) {
        regId = registerGCM();
        Log.d("RegisterActivity", "GCM RegId: " + regId);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Already Registered with GCM Server!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public String registerGCM() {

    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
    regId = getRegistrationId(context);
    System.out.println("Inside registerGCM method"+regId);
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(regId)) {

        registerInBackground();

        Log.d("RegisterActivity",
                "registerGCM - successfully registered with GCM server - regId: "
                        + regId);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "RegId already available. RegId: " + regId,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return regId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make the constructor of XWalkResponceClient like this

```
Context context
public XWalkResponceClient(Context context)
{

this.context=context;
}
```

now pass this context here

```
regId = registerGCM(context);
```

Comment: @Akshat-Implicit super constructor XWalkResourceClient() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructorthis error comes

Comment: try to pass the context to this activity or class anyhow.